# Retrieving information from a dict without using the key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary structure like the one shown below and I want to extract the `"EV=5.0"` part from it. Just the first instance of it that is.

```
my_dict = {('zone1', 'pcomp100002', '33x75'): {('Dummy', 'EV=5.0', -5.0, -5.0, -5.0): 68.49582}, ('zone1', 'pcomp100004', '33x75'): {('Dummy', 'EV=5.0', -5.0, -5.0, -5.0): 37.59079}}
```

Note that the only thing I know is the structure of the `dict` but not the actual master `keys` (e.g., `('zone1', 'pcomp100002', '33x75')`) or sub `keys` (e.g., `('Dummy', 'EV=5.0', -5.0, -5.0, -5.0`).

In other words, I know the location of the information I want to retrieve. Present in all sub `keys` in position 1.

I came up with two ways to do it but I like neither of them:

```
# method 1 - unreadable
print(list(list(my_dict.values())[0].keys())[0][1])

# method 2 - two loops broken in their first iteration
for i in a.values():
    for j in i:
        print(j[1])
        break
    break
```

Converting the whole dict to string and seraching for `"EV="` also occured to me but buit that was the ugliest thought I made in a long time.

Is there a better way that i am missing?

Comment: How about `[data[1] for key in my_dict.values() for data in key]`?

Comment: The actual dictionary is much much longer than the sample shown here so your list comprehension would not be very efficient. But if coupled with `next` we might be going somewhere

Comment: `next` will only return the first value. I don't know if that is what you want, that is why I posted as comment.

Comment: @Styvane It was not very clear from the question. One had to look at my code to realise it was only the first instance of it I was after. I updated the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could turn the version 2 to generator expression and use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#next):

```
>>> my_dict = {('zone1', 'pcomp100002', '33x75'): {('Dummy', 'EV=5.0', -5.0, -5.0, -5.0): 68.49582}, ('zone1', 'pcomp100004', '33x75'): {('Dummy', 'EV=5.0', -5.0, -5.0, -5.0): 37.59079}}
>>> next(k[1] for v in my_dict.values() for k in v)
'EV=5.0'
```

Comment: I think that's this is as good as it gonna get. Thanks!